# In this piece of code, why does 4%2 not equal 0?

Tags: java

I've been spending quite a bit of time trying to figure out why a line of code will just not function properly. I'm trying to 'activate' the following `if` statement in this piece of code:

`if (i%t == 0){
isPrimeNumber = false;
}`

However, when `i%t` truly DOES equal 0 (for example, when i=4 and t=2), `isPrimeNumber`'s value is never changed to false. Could someone enlighten me as to why this is happening? I would greatly appreciate any help I could get.

The entire segment:

```
for (int i = 2; i < maximumRange; i++){
        boolean isPrimeNumber = true;

        for (int t = 2; t < i; t++) {
            if (i%t == 0){
                isPrimeNumber = false;
            }
        }

        if (isPrimeNumber = true) {

            primeNumbers.add(i);

        }

    }
```

Comment: What do you think `if (isPrimeNumber = true)` does?  Perhaps you meant `if (isPrimeNumber)`?

Comment: It's always embarrassing when the problem turns out to be something like this.  Always a good laugh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (isPrimeNumber = true) {
```

This assign `true` to `isPrimeNumber`, then evaluates it as a boolean (which will always be true, since you just assigned it to be that)

Use `==` instead (or just leave it out, since `booleanVariable == true` is the same as `booleanVariable`, and you don't run the risk of making this sort of mistake).

Comment: God, I feel so dumb after reading that. Can't believe I missed such a simple mistake. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (isPrimeNumber = true)
```

to

```
if (isPrimeNumber)
```

The `=` is for `assignment`, not `equality`.